# Pass a command as argument for another command

Tags: macros

Second question today: is there a way to pass a command as an argument of another method?

```
\newcommand\foo[1]{Foo does: `#1'}
\newcommand\bar[2]{Bar does: `#1{#2}'}

...

\bar{\foo}{xxx}
```

The output I want should be:

```
Bar does: `Foo does: `xxx''
```

Also, can someone explain to me what `\expandafter` does?

EDIT:

Sorry, for the question, after re-reading my code a few times, I noticed the origin of the mistake: the `#1` in `\bar` was actually written `\#1` instead. Nonetheless, thank you all for the quick answers.

Comment: Your example should work as is, but not perhaps in the way you expect (`\foo` is expanded _after_ `\bar`).

Comment: From those definitions you get exactly what you are looking for. The question is a bit too vague, though.

Comment: (Please post one question at a time.  For `\expandafter` I recommend taking a look at TeX-by-Topic, it's free, online, and in TeXLive.)

Answer (score 10):

The following works for me:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\newcommand\Foo[1]{Foo does: `#1'}
\newcommand\BaBar[2]{BaBar does: `#1{#2}'}
\begin{document}
\BaBar{\Foo}{xxx}
\end{document}
```

perhaps you had an error `\bar already defined`? because I just copied your code and changed the name of the `\bar` command to avoid that error message.

Answer (score 2):

In TeX there are no methods  although you can define a macro in such a way as to be in many respects a `method`.

Consider the following minimal,

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\long\def\aPieceOfCode{%
  This is a Piece of code that I need to type out in a number of ways.
  First pick the contents from the CMS and store it in macro. Then call them through your typesetter macros and hey it can even display maths \formula\ without the use of JavaScript!
}

\def\formula{$a=b^2+23 $}
\def\displayMyCode#1{#1}

\displayMyCode{\aPieceOfCode}
\end{document}
```

You can think of the `\aPieceofCode` as a function or object. In the `displayMyCode` macro you can pass this as an argument.

Comment: Just a `\tiny` request: Would you guys please considder using the LaTeX definitions `\newcommand` and `\newcommand*` in place of the TeX `\long\def` and `\def` to prevent redefinition existing commands.  The same goes for all the `\hbox` and `\vbox` declarations I see everywhere here on Stackexchange. Using the TeX commands are very powerful in a TeXnicians hands, but can cause havoc for a newbee.

Comment: @Danie Els Good suggestion, will keep it in mind.