# Pass a macro (with arguments) as an argument for another macro

Tags: macros

In [Pass a command as argument for another command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16858/pass-a-command-as-argument-for-another-command), a notion of invoking TeX macros as methods was described. In my case, I'm attempting to use arguments within the call structure. My example below uses two passes of `\StrSubstitute` to replace characters that I want to modify:

```
\usepackage{xstring} % for StrSubstitute

\newcommand*{\changeslash}[1] {%
    \StrSubstitute{#1}{/}{5c}%
}
\newcommand*{\changedollars}[1] {%
    \StrSubstitute{#1}{\$}{24}%
}
\newcommand*{\changeboth}[1] {%
    \changeslash{\changedollars{#1}}%
}
```

I've experimented with adding `\expandafter` in different places, but this problem has me stumped.

Comment: Hi baitisj [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I edited your question just to make the link more descriptive, if you'd prefer it your way, feel free to roll back :)

Comment: Thank you, for both the welcome, and for the edit, cmhughes! As a new user of LaTeX (and of TeX.SE), I'm grateful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

`xstring` replacements do not work by expansion, but they need the input string to be expanded, thus adding `\expandafter` doesn't really help. You need to use the optional argument so that the string with the replacement is stored in a temporary macro, then you can use `\expandafter` to expand that macro to pass to the second call.  In addition as it fully expands its input in a way not entirely consistent with LaTeX `\protect` mechanism I needed to make `\$` e-tex protected.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring} % for StrSubstitute

\let\olddollar\$
\protected\def\${\olddollar}


\newcommand*{\changeslash}[1] {%
    \StrSubstitute{#1}{/}{5c}[\temp]%
}
\newcommand*{\changedollars}[1] {%
    \StrSubstitute{#1}{\$}{24}[\temp]%
}
\newcommand*{\changeboth}[1] {%
  \changedollars{#1}%
  \expandafter\changeslash\expandafter{\temp}%
}


\begin{document}


\changeslash{aaa/b\$bb}\temp


\changedollars{aaa/b\$bb}\temp


\changeboth{aaa/b\$bb}\temp

\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked beautifully, and I think it's clear enough that a newbie like me can begin to understand what is going on. I really appreciate the help, Dr. Carlisle!

Comment: In the example using StrSubstitute I am unable to wrap the result of change both with texttt. \texttt{\changeboth{A/B\$C}} Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

The problem seems to rely in two settings that you should apply:

```
\noexpandargs
\exploregroups
```

If I give your definitions and use those declarations, from

```
\changeboth{A/B\$C}
```

I get that LaTeX prints

> A5cB24C

which seems what you're expecting. However you'll have no way to retrieve the modified string. If instead you want to store the result in a macro for later usage, a different approach should be used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring} % for StrSubstitute

\newcommand*{\changeslash}[1]{%
    \StrSubstitute{#1}{/}{5c}[\temp]%
}
\newcommand*{\changedollars}[1]{%
    \StrSubstitute{#1}{\$}{24}[\temp]%
}
\newcommand*{\changeboth}[1]{%
  \changedollars{#1}%
  \expandafter\changeslash\expandafter{\temp}%
}

\begin{document}
\noexpandarg
\changeboth{A/B\$C}

\show\temp
\end{document}
```

This will produce no output, but TeX will print on the terminal

```
> \temp=macro:
->A5cB24C.
l.18 \show\temp
```

and you can freely use the changed string. Here `\exploregroups` is not needed.

---

A different approach uses LaTeX3 features.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% Document commands
\NewDocumentCommand{\changeslash}{ m }
 {
  \baitisj_change_slash:n { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\changedollars}{ m }
 {
  \baitisj_change_dollars:n { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\printchangedstring}{}
 {
  \tl_use:N \l_baitisj_string_tl
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\changeboth}{ m }
 {
  \baitisj_change_dollars:n { #1 }
  \baitisj_change_slash:V \l_baitisj_string_tl
 }

% Variables and functions
\tl_new:N \l_baitisj_string_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \baitisj_change_slash:n #1
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_baitisj_string_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_baitisj_string_tl { / } { 5c }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \baitisj_change_dollars:n #1
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_baitisj_string_tl { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_baitisj_string_tl { \$ } { 24 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \baitisj_change_slash:n { V }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\changeboth{A/B\$C}
\printchangedstring

\end{document}
```

The scheme for extending this to more substitutions seems clear. It depends on your application using `\printchangedstring` or using the modified string in other ways.

**Note** In any case (`xstring` or `xparse` method), if you need to change the *literal* `$` into `24`, don't use `\$`, but simply `$`.

Answer (score 2):

Citing from the xstring documentation explains why your approach does not work:

> When full expansion mode is activated with \fullexpandarg, arguments are expanded with an \edef before they are read by the macro.
>
> The macros of this package are not purely expandable, i.e. they cannot be put in the argument of an \edef. Nestling macros is not possible neither.

So this probably does not really help you, but you might have something to look for. It might be easier to help you from here on, if you would state a question.